# How to update S3 bucket with expire date using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I would like to update the S3 bucket with the new content(create a folder within a bucket). What is the `--expires` date format. I didn't find any examples using `AWS CLI` on google. Can someone please help me on this  thing?

Something like this:

```
aws s3 sync $backup_home s3://backup/$app-backup/$app-$DATE --expires '$DATE'
```

Comment: Just checking... what do you think `--expires` does?  It may not be what you expect.

Comment: object is no longer cacheable after that date.

Comment: Yes, by web browsers.  This sets the `Expired:` header to a fixed value when the object is subsequently downloaded.  It's not usually very useful.  Setting `Cache-Control:` is the recommended practice, and when this header is present, [`Expires:` is supposed to be ignored](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.3).  I asked, because I thought perhaps you had this confused with [`x-amz-expiration` and lifecycle policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/), which is not a value that you can set -- it's calculated by S3 based on the policy.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael. This is so helpful :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`aws s3 sync` expects a GMT [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) datetime string as the format for the `--expires` option. Something like this:

```
aws s3 sync --expires '2016-06-14T00:00:00Z' $backup_home s3://backup/$app-backup/$app-$DATE
```

The ISO 8601 standard allow simple dates, so if the exact time of day your object expires doesn't matter and you want to use a relative time in the future you can use this bash shell syntax:

```
  --expires "$(date -I -d '30 days')"
```

The `-I` flag enables ISO 8601 date formatting and the `-d` flag tells the `date` command to print the date described by the following string.

Comment: You can use the `date` command with `--expires`, like `--expires  "$(date -d '+6 months' --utc +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')"`.